# How do I set ${user} in Eclipse to get the correct @author tag?

Tags: eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the value of ${user} variable used in Eclipse templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246192/how-to-change-the-value-of-user-variable-used-in-eclipse-templates)

I am using Eclipse and every time code is created, @author is set to the value of ${user}.
Unfortunately,${user} seems to contain my windows login id. 
Is there a way to override this through Eclipse?
I couldn't find the option.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a way in Eclipse itself. But from what I can find, `${user}` uses the value of the `user.name` environment variable; therefore, you can pass `-Duser.name=My Name` in eclipse.ini to override it.

Or, if you prefer, you can modify the shortcut to point to:

```
C:/java/eclipse/eclipse.exe -vmargs -Duser.name="cleverUserNameToUseInSourceCode"
```

as shown in [this blog entry](http://morlhon.net/blog/2005/09/07/eclipse-username/comment-page-1/).

[image: @author ${user}]

Comment: For those not sure where to find the eclipse.ini file, it is probably located in the Eclipse installation directory (or for Mac in the Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS). This means if you have multiple installations of Eclipse, you will have to change each one individually. [Reference](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini)

Comment: It might help to mention that the `-Duser.name` option needs to come after the `-vmargs` flag in the `eclipse.ini` file.  Also, spaces are acceptable and camel case isn't necessary.

Comment: If you have EclipsePDT from Zend the eclipse.ini file might be called `zend-eclipse-php.ini` and sits in the main installation folder of Eclipse.

Comment: Since the blog link is down here is more information:  http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Comment: A flexible solution using EGit can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246192/how-to-change-the-value-of-user-variable-used-in-eclipse-templates/41412349#41412349)

Answer (score 182):

```
Windows > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Code Templates > Comments
```

Select `Types` and edit the template to insert another value (possibly a fixed one for now, or change the [user.name property](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.jdt/msg18308.html) as mmyers suggests)

```
/**
 * @author myUserValue
 *
 * ${tags}
 */
```

[image: Code Template preferences]

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359351/eclipse-overriding-user-name-in-config-ini

Comment: I found this helpful due to the fact the best way to sign my name is with my university email address instead of just my system username; which isn't very self identifying.

Comment: This doesn't address adding the @author tag to an existing file

Comment: @DavidWebb that would be because it was not what the question was about.

Comment: The question was how to "How do I set ${user} ..", not "how do I edit the template to use a static hard coded String instead of ${user}".  Agree to disagree. :)  Might want to read it again.