# How do I change the Javadocs template generated in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, javadoc

I dislike the default Javadocs generated for me when I create a Class or methods, especially the @author variable, which is the current system username on my windows box.

I would like to change it. Is this possible?

Comment: For the `@author` variable customization, you can set up your custom string by editing `eclipse.ini` file adding `-Duser.name=customstring` (Tested in **Kepler / Luna**)

Comment: You better get rid of `@author` tag, as it is an [unwanted noise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17271433/1800052).

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Check `Preferences / Java / Code Style / Code Template`

Section `Comment / Type`

You can replace the `author` tag by whatever value you need and it will have an effect on new generated classes.

[image: Code Templates]

---

However, if the template is fine, but the value referenced buy the author tag is not, see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935711/how-do-i-set-user-in-eclipse-to-get-the-correct-author-tag):

`${user}` uses the value of the `user.name` environment variable; therefore, you can pass `-Duser.name=My Name` in `eclipse.ini` to override it.

Or, if you prefer, you can modify the shortcut to point to:

```
C:/java/eclipse/eclipse.exe -vmargs -Duser.name="cleverUserNameToUseInSourceCode"
```

---

- MacOs: [Aram Kocharyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/549848/aram-kocharyan) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612633/how-do-i-change-the-javadocs-template-generated-in-eclipse#comment15694930_2612688) the `eclipse.ini` is in `Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/` if you right click and go Show Package Content.
- ZendStudio: [rofflox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/764233/rofflox) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612633/how-do-i-change-the-javadocs-template-generated-in-eclipse#comment24304614_2612688) the file is named `ZendStudio.ini` and is found in `Applications/Zend Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/`.

Comment: Unrelated: How did you generate such a pretty screenshot?

Comment: @Paul: after that meme revealed itself as "mandatory" (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775), I had to use FSCapture (http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm) to comply ;)

Comment: Snipping Tool does the trick on Win7. Thanks for the screenshot. This is just what I needed tonight! :)

Comment: For Mac users, eclipse.ini is in Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/ if you right click and go Show Package Contents

Comment: The same goes for Zend Studio for Mac. The `ZendStudio.ini` is found in `Applications/Zend Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/`.

Comment: Although this is not the answer what I want, this helps to get to the answer. I need to start each file with commented copyright and that can be done by editing `Files` instead of `Types`.

Comment: eclipse.ini has moved to Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse

Comment: @MichaelFulton Do you mean on Mac? Strange, because https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini still indicated `/MacOS/`

Comment: @VonC Hm. This is just where it was for me. I installed Neon.3 using the installer and looked for Eclipse.ini moments later.

Answer (score 6):

Look at Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Templates.

Comment: Yeah I know about that, but unfortunately this does not seem to have any effect on the code generation for Classes.

I want to avoid having to do this manually

Answer (score 3):

Spring Tool Suite (popular Eclipse customization for Spring development) uses STS.ini. On Windows I found it in the same dir as an app launch executable.

Comment: For STS on Mac OS see VonC's answer while searching through the STS application package.

Answer (score 3):

To use a Git username and email you can use the variables `${name:git_config(user.name)}` and
`${email:git_config(user.email)}`.

[image]

Comment: This is located under `Preferences / Java / Code Style / Code Templates / Comments / Types`

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [JAutodoc](http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/), which is a very useful plugin for Eclipse. The parametrization is way more advanced than the standard Eclipse generation.

Comment: Is there a way to replace the eclipse javadoc generation of eclipse with JAutoDoc? What I mean is: I have installing the JAutoDoc plugin. If I now generate get/setter methods via Shft+Alt+S and selecting "Generate Getters and Setters..." the javadoc comments are still generated by eclipse. But I want to generate this comments by JAutoDoc automatically...