# Java doc template

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm trying to put Java comments and I have used for that Java doc tamplate and STS tool :
 In STS I'm using that configuration in Java doc tamplate:-

```
/**
 * Description: 
 * Name of Project: ${project_name}
 * Created on: ${date} ${time}
 * Modified on: ${date} ${time}
 * @author ${user}
 * Version: 1.0
 * ${tags}
 */
```

Which displays the following on my Java file.

```
/**
 * Description: 
 * Name of Project: CabFMS
 * Created on: Oct 29, 2012 4:05:38 PM
 * Modified on: Oct 29, 2012 4:05:38 PM
 * @author tgupta1
 * Version: 1.0
 */
```

Here, I want to update the version dynamically just like `date`, `time`, `user`, `project_name` etc.

Please suggest me, is there a way for that or we need to do it manually?

Comment: I'm sorry but at least I cannot follow what you say.

Comment: Here you may find the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612633/how-do-i-change-the-javadocs-template-generated-in-eclipse

Comment: So do you want the comment to automatically update the version number when someone makes a change?

Comment: The Cat :Yes you are right i am looking for the same.....

Comment: Sorry, what is STS? [Wikipedia's list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS_(disambiguation)) doesn't show anything I could recognize as fitting.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann SpringSource Tool Suite, an Eclipse Distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [JAutoDoc](http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/) plugin might help you regenerating all the headers of your source files (if that what you are searching for).

Btw including created/modified/authors can be done easily and automatically with any source versioning systems like [SVN](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html), [Git](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html#Keyword-Expansion) or [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/KeywordExtension). However, their usage is [highly discouraged](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/44750) (it simply cause too much noise when diffing).