Eclipse PyDev - automatic author comment
I am using PyDev plug in in eclipse. I want to edit or disable the @author comment it adds to each new file, how do I do this? I want to either modify the username, or disable this functionality completely. How do I do this?

What have you tried so far? Have you tried whether it works as for Java: https://stackoverflow.com/q/935711/6505250

You can edit the New Module templates at PyDev > Editor > Templates (sort by the Context to get the ones related to creating a module first).

Alternatively you could reach there when you create a module > Config available templates... (see link in image below).

