# Eclipse does not launch (Ubuntu) : JVM terminated. Exit code=13

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, jvm

I have a problem with Eclipse. When I try to launch it, I get this error message:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/usr/bin/java
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.dist.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins       /org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.dist/eclipse_1407.so
-startup /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.dist.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata a8004
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.dist.jar
```

I have found the same error code but not the same text below, and the proposed solutions didn't work.

Can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13

Comment: What does *java --version* say? Eclipse doesn't work very well with the Java runtime that comes with most versions of Ubuntu, you need the Sun/Oracle JDK.

Comment: @Daff i'm using it with openjdk 7/ubuntu every day and it works flawlessly. I think i didn't have a single crash since a year or so (was using sun jdk before). So maybe update to 7 is enough.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9636283/405117 helped me

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Usually has to do with incompatible architectures of Eclipse and the JVM. I am betting you got eclipse 32 bit trying to run on 64 bit jvm.

Comment: How do I check the architecture of Eclipse and JVM ?

Comment: for java: java -version.
for eclipse: not sure actually. I just remember what I downloaded

Comment: java version "1.6.0_23"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_23-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)

Comment: I opened the eclipse dir , and found eclipse.ini file it has some plugins details that are 64 bit. maybe you can find out the same way :).  and I am guessing since there is no bit version for your java environment that is 32 bit. since I got the sun java and openjdk 64 bit and they both say 64 bit.

Comment: actually for sure. the eclipse error message says:  - arch: x86_64. so yep. jvm 32 bit and eclipse 64 bit. Resolved.

Comment: Yep that was that. Thanks for your help :).

Answer (score 20):

As mentioned above, you are most certainly using incompatible JVM.
Run the following command to check and set proper JVM:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: #Warning!!!!!!
This is not a linux commands code! This is  magic
It worked like a CHARM!!

Comment: Worked for me, and almost nothing ever seems to

Answer (score 0):

It is okay that the error message is different, because you are starting eclipse with different parameters and the error message is simply listing the parameters. Thus, the answers provided by google will work, and I think that the information provided in the following pages will be enough.

http://www.ehow.com/how_4784069_terminated-exit-code-error-eclipse.html

[Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)

Comment: " When you initially get the error message, you may see something that says "requiredJavaVersion=1.5", which will tell you what version of the JVM is required. "

The error message doesn't say that.

Comment: seems like you have a 32bit JVM but 64 bit eclipse. Download and try a 32bit version of eclipse (or 64 bit Java) and I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. It solved after, I have download JRE from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html

and put it in the path of eclipse as shown below -

abc@ubuntu:~/Downloads/eclipse$ ls

about_files

configuration

eclipse.ini

icon.xpm

p2 about.html

dropins

epl-v10.html

jre

plugins artifacts.xml

eclipse

features

notice.html

readme

I hope it helps.