# When Starting up Eclipse C/C++ it doesn't open but gives a error. Java was started but returned exit code=13

Tags: java, eclipse, exit

I just wanted to start learning programming in C so i downloaded Eclips C/C++ but when i try to launch it its says: Java was started but returned exit code=13.
But the normal eclipse for java works just fine.
Here is the eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

I haven't editted it in this one but i tried a few thing i have read but it didn't work. I have searched a lot but could find the answer.

Comment: better visit this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13

Comment: i've already read that and tried it but it dind't work and the normal Eclipse works just fine.

Comment: which java version you have installed?

Comment: java version "1.7.0_21"

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to start Eclipse, but are continually getting a "JVM terminated. Exit code=13" error" then you need to fix the error.

1. First, realize that this error is caused when you are attempting to start Eclipse using the wrong version of the Java Virtual Machine (JVM). So you need to realize what JVM you are starting with.
2. If you are using Linux, you can type "which java" on the command line. Otherwise, you can type "java -version". This will give you the Java version.
3. Now, you need to research the correct JVM for the version of Eclipse that you are using. For example, if you are using Eclipse Europa, it may require the 1.5 JVM to start. When you initially get the error message, you may see something that says "requiredJavaVersion=1.5", which will tell you what version of the JVM is required.
4. Make sure that you have the correct version of Java installed.
5. Now, you can either change the Java version environment variable or you can tell Eclipse to use a different version of the virtual machine upon startup. To do this you use the "vm" flag.
   For example: ./eclipse -vm /home/seed/app/jre1.5.0_10/bin
6. Now that you have changed the version of the Java Virtual Machine that you are using to start Eclipse, the error should be resolved.

For more details visit [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_4784069_terminated-exit-code-error-eclipse.html)

Comment: i've downloaded java runtime envoirment 5 and now it gives the error Java was started but  returned exit code=2

Answer (score 0):

I observed the following on a Windows 7 PC. Java update installed a new version on 2014-11-17. Eclipse 3.6 is OK. Eclipse 4.3 is OK. Eclipse 4.4 reported an error similar to "Java was started but returned exit code= 13".

I uninstalled the update with Control Panel  -> Programs and Features -> Uninstall.

Eclipse 4.4 started up normally after the uninstall