# How to Run Spring Tool Suit IDE in Windows

Tags: java, javascript, json, jquery

Hi can anyone help me on Spring Tool Suit IDE Running . I installed Spring Tool Suit IDE Running to my system and one shortcut is also created in my desktop but while clicking on that i am getting the following exception.!

java was started but return exit code =13

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13

Comment: hi i gone through the link but still it doesn't works for me now I am getting the following exception :the STS executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library . So can you plz help me on this...

Comment: Hi can anyone help me plz i am not able to run the Spring tool Suit IDE in windows 7 64 bit os ..I am getting following exception .STS executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library

Answer (score 0):

Initial I uninstall another Java SE Development Kit that you have installed in your pc, next I added the follow path in the *SpringToolSuite4.ini in my case: *(depends of your IDE that you´ve installed)

> **-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe**
>
> before -vmargs.