# Java was started but returned exit code = 13

Tags: java, eclipse

Before I begin, I am using a 64 bit OS (Windows 8), 64 bit Eclipse, and what I assume to be a 64 bit JDK since I reinstalled it before this attempt.  I've checked out many similar posts on SO over the past few hours, and while I think I've made some progress, none of the solutions seem to be working for me.

My error message:

> Java was started but returned exit code=13
>  C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
> -Xms40m
> -Xmx512m
> -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
> -jar C:\eclipse\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
> -os win32
> -ws win32
> -arch x86_64
> -showsplash
>  C:\eclipse\plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.3.1.v20130911-1000\splash.bmp
> -launcher C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe
> -name Eclipse
> --launcher.library
>  C:\eclipse\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835\eclipse_1503.dll
> -startup
>  C:\eclipse\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
> --launcher.appendVmargs
> -exitdata 171c_68
> -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
> -vm C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\javaw.exe
> -vmargs
> -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
> -Xms40m
> -Xmx512m
> -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
> -jar C:\eclipse\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar

Here is my eclipse.ini:

```
-startup<br />
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar<br />
--launcher.library<br />
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835<br />
-product<br />
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product<br />
--launcher.defaultAction<br />
openFile<br />
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize<br />
256M<br />
-showsplash<br />
org.eclipse.platform<br />
-vm<br />
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\bin\javaw.exe<br />
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize<br />
256m<br />
--launcher.defaultAction<br />
openFile<br />
--launcher.appendVmargs<br />
-vmargs<br />
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6<br />
-Xms40m<br />
-Xmx512m<br />
```

How to get Eclipse up and running?

Comment: i dont think it should be javaw.exe, do you have java.exe?

Comment: javaw.exe is absolutely fine here.

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to launch a 32-bit JVM with some 64-bit Eclipse libraries. The fact that your Java install is in `C:\Program Files (x86)` strongly suggests that it's a 32-bit installation. But the Eclipse launcher is the 64-bit version, and you're passing the 64-bit architecture flag `-arch x86_64`. You need to get things to match -- either by uninstalling your 32-bit JVM and installing a 64-bit one, or (not a good choice) installing a 32-bit version of Eclipse instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try going into your eclipse directory and

```
C:\EclipseMars>mklink javaw.exe "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin"
symbolic link created for javaw.exe <<===>> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin
```

where the path in C:\Program Files\ points to your 64bit jdb or jre javaw.exe

Answer (score 0):

Your jdk path in environment variable JAVA_HOME does not exist in your system . Due to improper shutdown of the system , your jdk gets deleted from program files/java folder . You need to reinstall jdk again .

Answer (score 0):

The solution which worked for me after struggling for couple of hours is below :

Open the `.ini` file and *add vm argument* to `.ini` file

> -vm
>
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\bin\javaw.exe

After the below tag in the .ini file

> --launcher.appendVmargs