# I get java code 13 error when i try to run eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to this and wanted to try my hand at android app development. so i downloaded the SDK and ADT from https://developer.android.com. after this i realized i needed a Java thing so i downloaded jdk1.8.0_20 from the Java Site . my ecplise folder is in c:\Android\ ( "Android" being a folder I created for this purpose) the Java i installed is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java . Also my system is running on a 64 bit windows 7 OS. Now when i run eclipse i get the following error.

```
Java was started but returned exit code=13
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-jar C:\Android\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86_64
-showsplash C:\Android\eclipse\\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200\splash.bmp
-launcher C:\Android\eclipse\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
--launcher.labrary          C:\Android\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807\eclipse_1503.dll
-startup C:\Android\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exit data f24_5c
-
-launcher.library plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct
-
-launcher.XXMaxPermSize256m
-
-launcher.defaultAction openfile
-vm C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-jar C:\Android\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
```

now after all this i checked the eclipse.ini file and this is what it had

```
-startup plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-
-launcher.library plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct
-showsplash org.eclipse.platform
-
-launcher.XXMaxPermSize256m
-
-launcher.defaultAction openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

So can someone please help me and tell me what to do.. or better still tell me what i need to download and install on my 64bit windows 7 system so I can start learning some android app development.
your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem happen overnight when I hadn't changed anything.  I suspect that there was a auto-update of `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java`.

I solved this problem simply by renaming `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java` to `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\JavaXXX` so it isn't found and $JAVA_HOME is used instead.

I don't have time to look into this any further and will if my change breaks something else :(

Answer (score 1):

un-installing Java 32 bits and installing 64 bits did the trick for me.

https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

Answer (score 1):

I had this error occur yesterday.
Here is how I solved it, at least for Windows 7.
Go to Control Panel -> Appearance and Personalization
Under Folder Options

Click "Show Hidden Files and Folders"
Which looks like this
Now you're ready to solve the issue.

Navigate to the path that the error code gives you.
[Win]+[E] to open explorer in root.
Once you locate the folder Java inside the "Oracle" directory. Delete it.
Once you have done this.

try to start Eclipse again. Eclipse should now be able to find java again via. your JAVA_HOME variable in your path.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have working with either 32bit or 64 bit eclipse and java. 
use both either 32 bit or 64 bit.
have look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13)

Answer (score 0):

The Android SDK does not support Java 8. You have to install Java 7. And verify that Android xbit version is the same xbit version than the Java installed

Answer (score 0):

you need to instal JDK v8 because you upgrade your version of JAVA :D open start and write cmd open the console and put: java -version  and maby you have this:

java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

so, upgrade your JDK bro! :D

Comment: youcan download your JDK in [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)_italic_ **bold**