# Eclipse says java started but returned with exit code =13

Tags: eclipse

I am having JDK version 8 . Here is eclipse.ini file

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: You are running a 64 bit Eclipse so you need a 64 bit Java

Comment: Go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13)