# Eclipse won't start after Java update

Tags: java, eclipse

I updated Java and now Eclipse won't start, it says Java was started but returned exit code = 13. Eclipse was working just fine until this update. Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4945178/814416

Comment: check your java version whether it is 32/64-bit and then check eclipse, it is 32/64-bit, it might not compatible with your eclipse version....
Also,, [Your question is Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you may have downloaded the incorrect version for you computer? as in a 64 bit/ 32 bit conflict.

I found a similar problem to yours on another stackoverflow thread.

[Can't start Eclipse - Java was started but returned exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13)

Comment: That's same as i comment on question **Your question is Duplicate** (See that Link)...  
You can also **flag** the question as duplicate...  ;)

Comment: Thank you, your link helped me solve the problem. The Path environment variable and the directory to java in eclipse.ini did not agree, so all I had to do was change the directory in eclipse.ini to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin. The java update must have changed my path for some reason. Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

You can fix it by changing the directory of line "vm" in `eclipse.ini` to the version you have just installed.
Ex: I just updated my java to java 8 update 131 to java8 update 144
`C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/bin`

Change it to:
`C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_144/bin`

Note: On Windows, you can check your java in `C:/Program Files/Java` or `C:/Program Files(x86)/Java` depending on 64 or 32 bit installation.

Answer (score -1):

re-install java jdk to solve the problem