# Start up error while opening eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, startup-error

I have Eclipse in my computer and is running perfectly, after I install maven plugin and my java update itself, when I open eclipse, it show this message: "java was started but returned exit code=13", someone can help me?

Here is my java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Here is my eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

and I also find that `javaw.exe` , `java.exe` and `javaws.exe` are 0 Kb in

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath, I think it cause the problem, how can i fix it?
```

[Here is the link to my start up error](http://postimg.org/image/yzj3gmfkh/)

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add vm argument to eclipse.ini file which points to your jdk installation directory. For example like this:

```
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

The argument needs to be just before the `-vmargs` argument and needs to have a new line as in the example above

Java 8 support in eclipse is available since [Eclipse Luna](http://eclipse.org/downloads/java8/) (4.4) or with a patched Eclipse Kepler (4.3.2) as described [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler)