# When i click on eclipse.exe it's not running and showing error?

Tags: java, eclipse

**When i click on eclipse.exe it's not running and showing error !.How to resolve it? thanks.**[image]

Comment: You have a 64 bit Eclipse and almost certainly a 32 bit Java. They must both be 64 bit or both 32 bit.

Comment: The contents of eclipse.ini?

Comment: Number 13 is always unlucky

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you are running a 32bit java and a 64bit eclipse. Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/11461676/1897983.

Comment: You can try to download a `jre` and put it in `<your eclipse folder>/jre`, then you wont be relying on the systems `jre`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I just had to install 64bit JDK(Java Development Kit) to get resolved my problem thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Reason 1:** The most common reason behind this problem is, we are trying to install different bit version-that is, 64 bit or 32 bit  version of the software. It maybe either Eclipse or Java.

**Reason 2:** Configuration mistake in `Eclipse.ini`  file

**Reason 3:** Special characters ( #, !, @) in Eclipse installation directory

**Reason 4:** You maybe using latest version of Eclipse, but you might be using  wrong version or unsupported version  of Java Virtual Machine (JVM)

The above are the main reasons causing that Exit code =13 in Eclipse.