# How to Set Java Path On Windows?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, youtube

When we set the environment path, can't it work correctly for Java, Eclipse and Android Studio?
How to set it correctly?

When I set it temporarily by using the command prompt, set path is not working correctly.
So I tried to set it permanently by using the environment variable Path, but it's not possible.

How can I set it properly?
Please give me a detailed explanation

Comment: Look at this once http://stackoverflow.com/a/11461676/4404791

Comment: I am try it,,, but failed

Comment: You can never get success then. Watch videos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from setting the **JAVA_HOME** system variable you need to set the **Path** variable as well because the **Path** is the system variable that your Operating system uses to locate the needed executable from the terminal window.

So for setting the Path Variable proceed as follows:

- Right click on the My Computer icon --> Properties -->Advanced system settings --> Environment Variables
- Now under System variable scroll to the **Path** variable
- Select Path variable and click on edit button
- Now add %JAVA_HOME%\bin in the end of Variable values, separating this value form the existing one in the list with a ;
  eg xxxxx;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;

Note that before following the above steps also check if your JAVA_HOME variable is properly set. For doing this go to command prompt and type **echo %JAVA_HOME%**. If it is properly set then it will give you the path of your jdk.

***NOTE:*** Sometimes it happens that both the **Path** and **JAVA_HOME** variables are set properly but still things are not working.To avoid this run the command prompt as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio uses JAVA_HOME variable , not Path variable. So You should set up JAVA_HOME Variable.

- Right-click the My Computer icon on
  your desktop and select Properties
- Click the Advanced tab. Click the
  Environment Variables button.
- Under System Variables, click New.
- Enter the variable name as JAVA_HOME.
- Enter the variable value as the installation path for the Java Development Kit.

Note:Normally
installation path is like "**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0**"

Comment: What is the use of jre

Comment: jre for running  java applications and jdk for compiling java applications