# How to fix this error on tabula.read_pdf() function in Python

Tags: python, tabula, tabula-py

I am trying to extract tables from a PDF file using Python (Pycharm).

I tried the following code:

```
 from tabula import wrapper
 object = wrapper.read_pdf("C:/Users/Ojasvi/Desktop/sample.pdf")
```

However, the error i got was:

```
"tabula.errors.JavaNotFoundError: `java` command is not found from this Python process. Please ensure Java is installed and PATH is set for `java`"
```

Comment: Did you add `java` to your system `path`?

Comment: Read the section "Get tabula-py working"  at https://pypi.org/project/tabula-py

Comment: Can you please help me with that @dome

Comment: I think that those two post should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29204638/how-to-set-java-path-on-windows and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation. Let me know if it will work.

Comment: worked! thank you! @dome

Comment: I posted the answer. Can you upvote and accept it as I solved your problem?

Comment: You would need amazon corretto, an openJDK. [This process helped me solve the issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68479840/8150584)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to add `java` to your system `path`. You can check those posts, they should help you in solving your problem:

- [How to Set Java Path On Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29204638/how-to-set-java-path-on-windows)
- [Environment variables for java installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation)

Answer (score 1):

I had every thing setup Java installed and Java path setup but was still getting same error, after spending half a day , I did below and everything worked.

I was using a python environment and running Tabula in python environment. I was getting error mentioned in questions.

I changed my python environment basically default one which is no environment and everything worked. I think Tabula is not able to detect Java once we are inside an python environment.