# Eclipse Kepler just wont start due to Java issues

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

I am trying to run Eclipse Kepler at work and it just won't work. Every time I fixed one issue the next comes up.

At the moment it gives me the error:

> Java was started but returned exit code=13

[image]

I already edited the eclipse.ini after I found something similar on this page but it didn't help either.

My ini file is:

```
-startup

-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile

-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
-vm

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\javaw.exe
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m

-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Xms96m
-Xmx768m
-Xss1m
-XX:MaxPermSize=192m
```

Comment: [did you try this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13)

Comment: [or check out this one since it looks like you already found the other link](http://www.ashout.com/fix-java-started-returned-exit-code13-eclipse/)

Comment: yes I alredy tries java 64bit and 32bit Java verisions multiple times in different directories.

Comment: Next thing I will try is uninstall Java versions and all Java related stuff and start with a fresh one.

Comment: A dumb question just to make sure: The filename of the eclipse installation file i used was: kepler-SR2-20150122-1000-win32-win32-x86_64.  This is a 32bit version right? how can I check?

Comment: x86_64 means you have a 64 bit Eclipse, you must use a 64 bit Java with this.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I figured it out, now.

The reason was simply the large Number of Java installations on the laptop, that have uses lots of other people before me.

So I uninstalled all Java related stuff on the pc and ran the CCleaner. Then I freshly installed eclipse and java 7.

Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

your java version is 32 bit but your eclipse is x86_64(support 32 and 64 bit but usually encounter this error).
Try to download  eclipse 32 bit version.

Answer (score 0):

```html
To check your version of Java, run

 java -version 
in a console (command prompt). On Windows 7 with 64-bit Java 6 I get:

  java version "1.6.0_27"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_27-b07)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.2-b06, mixed mode)
Note the 3rd line, which shows that this is a 64-bit version.

On a 32-bit version you'll get something like:

  Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing) 

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```