# Spring Tool Suite launch error - Java was started but returned exit code=13

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I followed these following questions and answers:
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30372337/sts-launch-error-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13)

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27019786/eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-error-code-13), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13), [link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30372337/sts-launch-error-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13)

But still i am not getting solution for my problem. My STS.ini file is:
[STS.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao5uE.png),

And I got error is:[STS launching error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjHXC.png).

If anyone has solution please respond.

Comment: Please show your code in the question and not as screenshot.

Comment: [follow the this this link this will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30372337/sts-launch-error-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you clicked the download button on the [Spring Tool Suite site](https://spring.io/tools) it probably downloaded the 32-bit version (as the browser you used is, probably, 32 bit). I haven't found a way to determine which version you downloaded besides the name of the rar file

32 bits version file is named `spring-tool-suite-3.8.4.RELEASE-e4.6.3-win32.zip` and 64 bits is `spring-tool-suite-3.8.4.RELEASE-e4.6.3-win32-x86_64.zip` (notice the `-x86_64` at the end)

So, in order to fix your issue:

1. Confirm that you are using 64 bit Java

   1.1 Start a terminal (`cmd` at Windows) and run `java -version`
2. Download 64 bits Spring Tool Suite manually from its [download all versions page](https://spring.io/tools/sts/all)
3. Unzip
4. Execute `$UNZIPPED_FOLDER/sts-bundle/sts-3.8.4.RELEASE/STS.exe`
5. If everything goes ok mark this answer as correct ;)

I ran the same issue as you just an hour ago and that was the way I fixed it. For future downloads select manually which software version you want to download (as default selected will probably be 32 bits)

Answer (score 1):

The -vm argument in your STS.ini file has to be the first one in that file. Eclipse doesn't allow this argument to be placed anywhere else in that file. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved for me.
The problem is the 32 and 64bit versions.

I accidentally downloaded a 32bit version of the JDK 1.8 and a 64bit version of Spring Tools Suite 4

And for worse, I copied and pasted the environment variable JAVA_HOME without pay attention, pointing to C:\Program Files (x86)... :)

Then, I uninstall de JDK 32 bit and later installed the 64bit version.

create/set an environment variable and path like following:

variable name: JAVA_HOME
variable value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261
and finally, in Path, set %JAVA_HOME%\bin

My apologies for my horrible english

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error but it was because my JAVA_HOME was not set in PATH variable which sts.ini file was looking for.