# STS 3.9- Java was started but returned exit code=13

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

Following is the configuration:

1. windows 8.1 with 64-bit
2. jdk1.8.0_131
3. jre1.8.0_131
4. sts-3.9.0 for 64-bit

when I am trying to start STS(Spring tool suite) I am getting following error and unable to start the STS(Image attached for error details)

Note: I have separate Eclipse neon in my machine which works perfectly.

[image]

Comment: You have a 64 bit STS and a 32 bit Java. They must both be 64 bit or both 32 bit.

Comment: I have STS and java both 64-bit installed in my machine. but still the problem persists.

Comment: You may have a 64 bit Java installed but STS is finding and trying to use a 32 bit Java. Exit code 13 always means a mismatch in 32/64 bit. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4945178/2670892) question

Comment: I have cross checked and found everything is 64 bit. I am really fade up with this. I am in deadlock situation. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can point the correct javaw.exe file for spring using a -vm argument on sts.ini file.

I just had to do it, here is how:
[STS launch error - Java was started but returned exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30372337/sts-launch-error-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13)

Hope it still helps, considering how old the question is.