# eclipse luna c++ error when opening

Tags: c++, eclipse

I was starting to work with the eclipse Luna IDE on c++ projects and everything worked fine, until I installed a jdk in order to work with an eclipse keppler IDE for java. I can use keppler now but now eclipse Luna throws this problem when I try to open it (link to the image):

http://puu.sh/jefv0/181ba9d94c.png

Does anybody know the solution or what happened?

Comment: Did you look at this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13

Comment: I did, but I think it's different since he wants to use java, I want it to compile c++.