# I can't install eclipse due to a lot of errors

Tags: eclipse, sdk

I am having a lot of errors installing eclipse sdk.

It has a lot of errors at first saying,

`"Java was started but returned exit code = 13"`
`:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe`
`-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6`
`-XX.MaxPermSize=256m`
`-Xms512m`
`-Xmx1024m`
`-jar`

There is a lot more errors about .jar files, `.bmp`, the `eclipse.exe` itself, `eclipse_1503.dll`.

I just can't insert pictures here.

How can I fix these errors? I am very confused and I don't know how to solve just by searching through google.

Thanks in advance for those who can help. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't start Eclipse - Java was started but returned exit code=13](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13)

Comment: This means that your Java is 32 bit and Eclipse is 64 bit (or the other way round). They must both be 32 bit or both 64 bit.

Comment: How do I change it sir? I'm so confused.