# Trying to install Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to install Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers.

I have tried the 32 bit version & the 64 bit version (as I am never sure which is which)

> http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/mars/2/eclipse-jee-mars-2-win32.zip

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/mars/2/eclipse-jee-mars-2-win32-x86_64.zip

I keep getting the same error:

> Java was started but returned  exit code 13
>   C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
>   -Disgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
>   -Xms256m
>   -Xmx1024m
>   -jar C:\eclipse-jee-mars-2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins/org.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
>   -os win32
>   -ws win32
>   -arch x86_64
>   -showsplash C:\eclipse-jee-mars-2-win32=x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.5.2.v20160212-1500\splash.bmp
>   -launcher C:\eclipse-jee-mars-2-win32_x86_64\eclipse\eclipse.exe
>   -name Eclipse
>   --launcher.library C:\eclipse-jee-mars-2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins/org.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417\eclips_1611.dll
>   -startup C:\eclipse-jee-mars-2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins/org.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
>   --launcher.appendVmargs
>   -exitdata 2918_68
>   -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
>   -vm C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
>   -vmargs
>   -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
>   -Xms256m
>   -Xmx1024m
>   -jar C:\eclipse-jee-mars-2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins/org.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar

I had to copy all that gobbledegook by hand!

What does it mean? How do I fix it?

Comment: please check this, similar issue `java return code 13` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13

Comment: can you do a `java -version` and post the same..

Comment: You are using a 64 bit Eclipse and a 32 bit Java. They must both be 32 bit or both 64 bit.

Comment: I already read the existing answers. If i had found an answer I understood, I wouldn't be asking!

Comment: java -version
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Cracked it. Installed 64 bit Java!