# While installing eclipse IDE for java I gets an error?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I am trying to install eclipse IDE for java on windows 10. I have already installed java 13.0.1. When i click on eclipse.exe it says an error is occurred see the log file. So here is the log file

```
!SESSION 2020-05-10 00:04:30.055 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.M20130911-1000
java.version=13.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2020-05-10 00:04:30.595
!MESSAGE Startup error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch(Framework.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:225)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The System Bundle could not be resolved: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.checkSystemState(BaseStorage.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.getStateManager(BaseStorage.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.getState(BaseAdaptor.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.frameworkStart(BaseStorage.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.frameworkStart(BaseAdaptor.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start(SystemBundleActivator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 12 more
```

I have already checked these links to solve my problem. But neither of them worked for me.
[Error while installing Eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41674861/error-while-installing-eclipse-ide)

[Trying to install Eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35657212/trying-to-install-eclipse-ide)

Comment: That is a very old Eclipse (4.3 from 2013) which will not run with Java 13. Use the current Eclipse 2020-03

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, you are using a really old version of Eclipse while you are using one of the newer versions of java. That version of Eclipse doesn't support that version of java, so you are getting an error. So, [download the newest version of Eclipse.](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)