# Error while running Eclipse,Java started but returned exit code=13

Tags: eclipse

While running eclipse, i found the below error :-

Java started but returned exit code=13

Below are the details from

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
2048m
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
2048m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\bin\javaw.exe
-Xmx512m
-vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin\javaw.exe"
-vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe"
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
```

I checked other forums too, but didn't get the appropriate answer.Please help

Comment: You are using a 32 bit Eclipse with a 64 bit Java. Note that in the eclipse.ini `-vm` must be on a separate line to the path and there should be no quotes around the path.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4945178/2670892

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't start Eclipse - Java was started but returned exit code=13](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13)