# Can't seem to open Eclipse Kepler [first time user]

Tags: java, eclipse, kepler

I installed Java7(64bit), EclipseKepler(64bit) and my OS is Win10(64bit) also how can I fix this?

[image: I have the error message here.]

Comment: You have a 64 bit Eclipse and a 32 bit Java. They must both be 64 bit or both 32 bit. Also Eclipse Kepler is really old, move to the latest Eclipse (Neon).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a Java version which is of 32 bit, where the eclipse is picking up.
Follow the instructions written here in the post [Can't start Eclipse - Java was started but returned exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13)

and it should solve your problem.

cheers,

Saurav