# STS - Java was started but returned exit code=13

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I just Downloaded STS to develop my first Spring boot application, but unfortunately I get this error: Java was started but returned exit code=13. See the image below :

[image]

I tried All the steps in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13), But it doesn't work.

My STS zip file name : `spring-tool-suite-3.8.1.RELEASE-e4.6-win32-x86_64.zip`

My Java version :

```
C:\Users\open>java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode, sharing)
```

After I removed that entry (`C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`) from the PATH, I get this new error.

[image]

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You have a 64 bit Eclipse/STS and a 32 bit Java. They must both be 64 bit or both 32 bit.

Comment: @greg-449 You are right. I dont know how I downloaded a 64bit version. Thank you