# exit code = 13 when running eclipse in windows

Tags: java, eclipse

I got an error of `exit code = 13` when trying to run eclipse and based on an answer from stack overflow, it said to modify my `eclipse.ini` file based on this site. https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Windows_Example

I went here and modified my `eclipse.ini` file and added
-vm

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\javaw.exe
```

This gave me an error of exit code = 1 and the site said to add this line
-vm

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

So I added that by itself and got the same error, then I added both lines and still got the same error.  Would anyone be able to help me.  I am adding an image of the error and my code.

Thanks

This is my eclipse.ini file

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-vm
C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\javaw.exe
-vm
C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

[Eclipse error and eclipse.ini file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpFRG.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't start Eclipse - Java was started but returned exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13)

Comment: _I know this is not a duplicate for this specific problem, but there is an answer below, now if someone came here, it will be easy to find the other solution for error 13 in eclipse_

Answer (score 1):

You have two different sets of `-vm` lines. You should only have one. Both of them also point to 32-bit copies of Java, which will not run a 64-bit version of Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I had to load the 64 bit version of Java to get it to run and I pointed the -vm lines to Program Files instead of Program Files (x86).  I did get it to run.