# Getting an error "error while loading shared libraries: libmpi.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Tags: eclipse, omnet++, veins

Getting an error "error while loading shared libraries: libmpi.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"  while running veins simulation in Omnet++

[image]

EDIT:

I reinstalled the omnet++ and now I am getting this error:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/home/jayabalan/usr/omnetpp-4.6/ide/jre/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=320m
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=/home/jayabalan/usr/omnetpp-4.6/bin/../ide/../samples
-jar /home/jayabalan/usr/omnetpp-4.6/ide//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /home/jayabalan/usr/omnetpp-4.6/ide/omnetpp
-name OMNeT++ IDE
--launcher.library /home/jayabalan/usr/omnetpp-4.6/ide//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326/eclipse_1605.so
-startup /home/jayabalan/usr/omnetpp-4.6/ide//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 340021
-vm /home/jayabalan/usr/omnetpp-4.6/ide/jre/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=320m
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=/home/jayabalan/usr/omnetpp-4.6/bin/../ide/../samples
-jar /home/jayabalan/usr/omnetpp-4.6/ide//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
```

Comment: I reinstalled Omnet and now I am getting this error on a new window:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Second error:

The almost certainly a Java SDK/JDK version problem or path problem preventing the Eclispe enviroment from starting.

Check your Java version:

```
$ java -version
```

Because of the

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
```

output in the error log suggest its looking for 1.7.

Then check this post describing many solutions to this problem:

[Can't start Eclipse - Java was started but returned exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13)

Comment: Thanks! I was using jdk 1.8. Downgrading to 1.7 made it work!

Comment: <!> Error in module (Veins::TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd) RSUExampleScenario.manager (id=6) at event #14, t=1.3: Model error: Connection to TraCI server closed unexpectedly. Check your server's log.

Comment: I am getting the above error on running the veins example on the Omnet++

Comment: Yup, never used OMNet++ so can't really help unfortunatly. Looks like the enviroment up and running now though and just some configuration of the host machine or other entities will get it running.

Answer (score 1):

### First error:

Either of two things may be happening (or both):

1 – You do not have the specific lib (unlikely because the compiler and linker would have built and linked with the library symbols).

2 – The path is not correct and the binary at runtime cannot locate the lib correctly.

I assume you are using a Linux flavour, I also noticed that you have a double set of colons appended within both your environment variables i.e. ( :: )

```
$PATH
$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Which could be the result of you appending the paths to the variables incorrectly (try removing one of the colons by appending the environment variable again without a colon).

For example:

Appending to existing environment variable

print my current environment variable to console:
(same for LD_LIBRARY_PATH)

```
VirtualBox:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/polysync/utils/x86_64.linux/bin:/usr/local/polysync/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Append a new path to the end of $PATH

```
export PATH=$PATH:/boom/yea

VirtualBox:~$ echo $PATH

/usr/local/polysync/utils/x86_64.linux/bin:/usr/local/polysync/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/boom/yea
```

Scroll along to see the appended path.

The following post describes the process very well:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path

Also check you have the lib by using:

```
VirtualBox:~$ sudo find / lib | grep libmpi.so.1
```

Hope this helps. You will need to log out and back in for Eclipse to see the changes. Would also be helpful if you posted strings instead of a screen shot (copy and paste the console output for eaxmple).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Halos! I am getting a new error after reinstalling Omnet++ and opening it