# Generate an error while open Teradata SQL assistant JAVA edition

Tags: java, sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

When i open Teradata SQL assistant JAVA edition then i got an error as mentioned below in image- 
[image: Error while open Teradata SQL assistant]

How to resolve this type of problem to open Teradata SQL assistant.

Comment: The Problem seems to be related to Java as `Teradata SQL Assistant` is built of top of `Eclipse Rich Client Platform (RCP)`. Check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13)

Comment: *SQL Assistant Java Edition* has been discontinued for several years, it probaby doesn't work with your Java version. Simply try http://downloads.teradata.com/download/tools/teradata-studio instead.

Comment: @dnoeth I work here in my company & here there is no any Teradata software tool for download. That's why i ask because no any option to install Teradata Studio.

Comment: Tell your manager that you can't install this old tool and need Studio to be able to do your work. Or is your company still using Windows XP, too :-)

Comment: Can you use plain old [SQL Assistant](https://downloads.teradata.com/download/tools/teradata-tools-and-utilities-windows-installation-package)?