# Can't launch Repast Simphony

Tags: repast-simphony

I just downloaded Repast Simphony 64 bit. I have Java 8v144 installed on my computer. When I start Repast I get an immediate exception that says

```
Eclipse


Java was started but returned exit code = 13
C:/ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
...
C:\Repast\Simphony-2.5\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0v20161219-1356.jar
...
etc.
```

I would appreciate suggestions about how to proceed.'

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This may be an issue with mismatched OS, Eclipse and JVM bitness, something along these lines: [Can't start Eclipse - Java was started but returned exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13)

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I've decided to use NetLogo instead of Repast.