# Event details in eclipse showing java version as 1.6 when i set my jdk version as 1.7

Tags: java, eclipse

When i am deploying an EAR file in which there are 58 projects . its showing an error which is

> oracle.eclipse.tools.webservices.WebServicesException:
>   weblogic.wsee.tools.WsBuildException: Error processing JAX-WS web
>   services

When i clicked that error in error log of eclipse it has opened in Event Details and its showing java version as 1.6 when my jdk version is 1.7. So how to convert my jdk version to 1.7 in event details of eclipse

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What java version have you in your eclipse.ini file? if it is an 1.6 version you should change it.

Comment: When i changed the java version of eclipse.ini file to 1.7 and closed the eclipse and restarted it its showing as "Java was started but returned exit code as 13.  C:/Oracle/middleware/jdk1.7.0_91/bin/javaw.exe"

Comment: it is may be a conflict between your OS and JDK bitness. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top]