# Cannot start Eclipse on Ubuntu exit code = 13

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, jvm

I cannot seem to get Eclipse running on my Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS machine.  I've installed, removed, reinstalled, purged, and reinstalled Eclipse to no avail.
I installed Eclipse using the Ubuntu repository:

```
# apt-get install eclipse
```

Some information about my machine:

```
$ uname -a
Linux $HOSTNAME 4.15.0-36-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 24 16:19:09 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ /usr/bin/java -version
openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.2, mixed mode)
```

Attempting to run Eclipse:

```
$ /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
An error has occurred.  See the log file
/home/$USER/.eclipse/155965261/configuration/1539424551911.log
```

A window pops up informing me

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/usr/bin/java
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.dist/eclipse_1503.so
-startup /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 64801c
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
```

The log file

```
!SESSION Sat Oct 13 02:55:51 MST 2018
------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2018-10-13 02:55:51.934
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find framework
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.getBootPath(Main.java:985)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

I've read similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13?rq=1) which instructed me to check the bitness, I am running a 64-bit OS with a 64-bit version of Java JDK, but I cannot seem to figure out how to check if my Eclipse installation is 64 or 32 bit (although I cannot imagine why apt-get would install a 32-bit package on my clearly 64-bit computer).  Other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13?noredirect=1&lq=1) suggested to check my eclipse.ini file, but I did not modify it from the default:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.dist
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
```

What can I do to further troubleshoot my installation?

Comment: `x86_64` in the launcher plugin id means Eclipse is 64 bit. But it looks like a very old version of Eclipse which doesn't understand Java 10. Use the current Eclipse version (SimRel 2018-09)

Comment: I don't know if it is suitable for you, but consider to use an eclipse installation via eclispse installer/downloadable archive in your userhome instead of the distribution package. This will also be more flexible with updates afterwards. You can also try to switch your java version using sdk-man.

Comment: @andi I am trying to install Eclipse for all users on the system, I tried manually installing into `/opt` first, but I got a strange error and that just felt like the wrong approach so I `rm -rf`ed the folder and tried using `apt-get` install