# Eclipse does not start when I run it and results in an error

Tags: java, eclipse

So I have been learning basic Java on this eclipse: "eclipse-inst-win64" and on this JDK version "jdk-12.0.2_windows-x64_bin" and everything works fine. So, I started a new course on spring and the teacher told us to download this version of eclipse: "Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers". I downloaded this file "eclipse-jee-2019-12-R-win32-x86_64" and when I extract the zip file and run the Eclipse application, this error pops up which is in the screenshot picture.[image: Error when running eclipse]

It worked fine for the instructor in the video.

Comment: look for eclipse.ini file and you can modify the java version in that file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't start Eclipse - Java was started but returned exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13)

Comment: You need to see which version of operating system you have,   64 bit or 32 bit. Then you download the corresponding version of JDK and eclipse.

Comment: My operating system is 64 bit and I've downloaded both the eclipse and jdk in 64 bit

Comment: Thanks for the website it was helpful and it worked finally.

Answer (score 0):

You are running a 64-bit Eclipse on a 32-bit Java (evidenced by the "Program Files (x86)" in the path).  That won't work.  You need to run Eclipse with a 64-bit Java.

Here is some documentation on how you can configure this:
   https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Windows_Example

Comment: I don't understand, the Java I downloaded is 64 bit.

Comment: I can't speak to what you have downloaded, but the error message shows that you were running a Java from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe".  The "Program Files (x86)" directory is for 32-bit programs.

Answer (score 0):

Exit code 13 shows that you have changed the java version. The change can be a switch from 64 to 32 bit java or vice versa.
Also check your JAVA_HOME to make sure it points to the correct one as well.

Comment: The jdk is 64 and I downloaded the "Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers" in 64 bit.