# Java was executed but returned exit code 13

Tags: java, eclipse

I have seen many answers related to this. But still not able to resolve.

1. I have verified that eclipse,OS and java are 64 BIT
2. Have set JAVA_HOME,JRE_HOME and PATH to:

   JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201

   JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201

   PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin
3. Also updated the eclipse.ini file with -vm before -vmargs

   -vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\bin\javaw.exe

But still when I launch eclipse I get the following error:

[image: error]

For verification of versions:

[image: commandpromptoutput]

In eclipse.ini we have:

org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64

Answer (score 0):

I quickly googled your error code. It seems you have downloaded the wrong version of Java:

*After knowing operating system version, make sure you downloaded the 64-bit version of Eclipse as well as a 64-bit version of Java software. If you downloaded 32-bit version (X86) of Java or eclipse any one of them, you will get that Exit code=13 error.*

It has also been asked before: [Can't start Eclipse - Java was started but returned exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13)

Comment: I have verified many times java and eclipse both are 64 bit

Comment: You may have several versions of Java installed. What do you get when you write java -version     and is it possible your computer is actually 32bit then?

Comment: I have added the screenshot to question

Comment: Check what kind of operativesystem you have, it seems to be windows but please try this in your terminal : systeminfo | findstr Build