# Eclipse IDE not starting up

Tags: java, eclipse

[image: The error]

I just reset my pc and installed the latest version of Java jdk and set the path and all,but on when starting the Eclipse application,this error pops up,what to do?

Comment: https://ashout.com/fix-java-started-returned-exit-code13-eclipse/

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13. It will help you definitely.

Answer (score 4):

Modify (or add if not already there) the `eclipse.ini` file (which is in your eclipse folder).

Next, right-click this file and select `Edit`.

```
-vm
your_java_path\bin\javaw.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

Found that i installed JDK for 32 bit but my system is 64 bit, anyway changing the JDK the error continues,I can't uninstall Eclipse,so just reinstalled from the setup.exe and it worked