# Downloaded Eclipse IDE recently and am facing this error message every time I try to open it. What is the cause behind it and how can I solve?

Tags: java, eclipse

[error message link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Cpok.png)

The error message I keep getting is shown in this link of the picture.

Comment: This might be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13

Comment: You recently downloaded a 9 year old release? Use the current version from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ instead.

Comment: That is an extremely old Eclipse (9 years and 19 releases old), use the current version.