# Eclipse installer showing this error in setup

Tags: eclipse

ERROR:

```
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf code=1002 Unable to read repository at https://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2022-06/202206091200/content.xml.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Update:

I again reinstalled Eclipse and now I am getting this error.

```
Java was started out but returned exit code =13
```

Comment: You are trying to download the content on Company network or personal pc without any firewall?

Comment: In company laptop with firewall and home network

Comment: Add proxy details in your eclipse and give a try, still if not working then company policy is blocking the download hence you need to connect with network team of your organization

Comment: how to add proxy details? and where do we get it?

Comment: i again reinstalled Eclipse and now m getting dis error. Java was started out but returned exit code =13

Comment: [eclipse java exit code 13 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-130) refer the link