# Error starting eclipse in ubuntu 16.04, JVM terminated, exit code =13

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, jvm, java-9

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, installed Eclipse IDE and using Java version 9. I am unable to start Eclipse. What should I do?

eclipse.in file:

[image]

Error I am getting:

[image]

Comment: what version of eclipse? does that support java9?

Comment: This other post may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230853/eclipse-does-not-launch-ubuntu-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13, where did you get the Eclipse installer?

Comment: You have a 64 bit Eclipse and a 32 Java. They must both be 64 bit or both 32 bit.

Comment: Is this a 64-bit JRE?

Comment: @greg-449 thank you , i will install 64 bit java .

Comment: @Saravana I didn't check properly. I am new to ubuntu and eclipse so I don't know how this version works.

Comment: @BrunoB.Carvalho I got the installer from official site. Its the latest version.

Comment: @greg-449 I checked my java version and I think its 64 bit. Here is the screenshot. https://snag.gy/6KhQUg.jpg

Comment: I note you are using Java 9 which is still in Beta. Eclipse does not support Java 9 yet, it is possible this is your problem.

Comment: Do not use openjdk-9 yet, use openjdk-8.