# Eclipse won't run - JVM Terminated, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, jvm

Please note:

I've checked other threads -

[Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)

[Eclipse does not launch (Ubuntu) : JVM terminated. Exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230853/eclipse-does-not-launch-ubuntu-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)

Which didn't seem to help in my case.

I've installed oracle java 8 package, `java -version` shows:

```
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

Eclipse was installed with 64-bit installer wizard from official website.
When trying to open eclipse i get the following:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-jar /home/adiel/eclipse/cpp-neon/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /home/adiel/eclipse/cpp-neon/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/adiel/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444/eclipse_1617.so
-startup /home/adiel/eclipse/cpp-neon/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 73000a
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-jar /home/adiel/eclipse/cpp-neon/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
```

My eclipse.ini file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
--launcher.library
/home/adiel/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
```

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS . Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Does `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -version` print 64-bit java as well?

Comment: 1. Confirm that you are really using the java you think you are via `which java`.

Comment: 2. Is there anything in your workspace log file? Can you delete or move the current workspace and try again?

Comment: @Tyler , `which java` shows `/usr/bin/java` for some reason. No workspace currently, i didn't get the chance to even create one. 

@JiriTousek , your input does print 64-bit java as well

Comment: Try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/761604/eclipse-not-working-in-16-04

Comment: Tried editing eclipse.ini as suggested. still doesn't work, but now produces a log file that reads: 

       `java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find framework
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.getBootPath(Main.java:1029)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.

Removed java-8-install using `sudo apt-get purge`,

Installed `openjdk-8-jdk` instead, then reinstalled eclipse package through their installer.

Now eclipse is working.