# Java exit code 13 on Eclipse RCP application (Indigo)

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling, 32bit-64bit

I seem to have a 32bit vs. 64bit problem here. It should be simple to solve, but I'm hoping you can help me by pointing out the problem. I really want to avoid re-installing OSs, Eclipse, several plugins, JDKs and JREs over and over again to find a working solution. Many thanks in advance!

I build on a 64bit Thinkpad, in 64bit Windows 7.
I have built an Eclipse RCP application in Indigo (3.7.1.), 32-bit version.
The only "Javas" I have on this machine is a 1.6.29 32bit JRE, and a 1.6.29 32bit JDK. I've installed these (perhaps in false assumption) to be able to build for 32bit systems, and not screw things up by building on a 64bit machine.

Seems I was wrong: when I export the application (as Eclipse product) I get the dreaded Java exit code=13:

[image: Startup exit code 13]

I am sure this is somehow to do with the combination of 32bit software on a 64bit system (if you can prove me wrong, even better!).

Does one of you know how I can set this up properly and still be able to build for win32?

Again, many thanks!

## UPDATE

I have installed 64-bit Eclipse 3.7.1, and JRE 1.6_30 + JDK 1.6_30, both 64-bit versions. However, **the error remains**! I think this might either be a bug, or I'm doing something else wrong.

First of all, here is the error message:
[image: Error message on start of eclipse.exe]

For this build, I didn't use the `Delta Pack` but instead added the RCP SDK `Software Site` to the target definition, choosing the option "include all environments" (or similar).

Also in the `target definition`, I set the target environment to `win32` (OS and WS) and `x86_64` (arch). Furthermore, I set the `Environment` to use the default JRE.

In the `product configuration`, I set the `Execution Environment` to JavaSE 1.6, and set the JRE to be packaged.

Also, here's my `eclipse.ini`:
    -startup
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
    --launcher.library
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502

Any ideas?

Comment: Was there any log file written in the configuration directory? Also try to start eclipse with the -console option.

Comment: Try option `-consoleLog` and launch eclipse via CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems this had *nothing* to do with 32-bit vs. 64-bit and *everything* with my lack of experience. The `product configuration` simply wasn't set up correctly. I've bypassed this by creating a new one which uses the automatically created plugin run config from when you start the application via the "Launch an Eclipse application" link in Eclipse itself.

For those who come across a similar problem, here is how it can be done.

1. Launch the application via "**Launch an Eclipse application**"
2. Go to **Run > Run Configurations**... and memorize the name of the run configuration
3. Create a new `Product Configuration`, and choose "**Use a launch configuration:**" in the wizard. From the dropdown list, choose the run configuration you have memorized in step 2.
4. Give the new product configuration an ID, Version and Name, and add further info (e.g., in the `Product Definition` section) as needed.
5. **Synchronize** and **Launch** from within Eclipse to see if everything works fine.
6. Export and be happy.

Comment: yes that's it. unfortunetelly eclipse documentation doesn't contain a best practices part.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to install everything as 64bit or 32bit system. That's a common problem with eclipse and I haven't found a better solution.

Comment: Thanks. I have installed everything (except Windows) as 32bit: Eclipse, JDK, JRE. This should be sufficient, shouldn't it? Still I get the error message. Do you mean I should install a 32bit Windows as well?

Comment: First try to install everything(Eclipse, JDK, JRE & Windows) as 64bit(Uninstall the 32bit versions first). I hope that would help you.

Comment: It doesn't work, even when everything is 64-bit :(. Please see the update. Thanks!

Comment: Although your answer hasn't solved *my* specific problem, I think it's very important to stress that mixing n-bit versions of OS, JDK, JRE and Eclipse may well lead to problems. And since I'll lose them 50 points anyway, I think it's just fair that you should have them by way of bounty :). Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried clean windows(32 bit) installation? A friend of mine tried to install/uninstall JDK & JRA & eclipse, but after clean windows install and properly selected JDK & JRA & eclipse(same as windows n-bit version) was working everything nice. Thanks for the 50 points and merry christmas :)

Comment: No, I didn't have to do that. Works all fine in 64-bit Win7 now :).

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse website tells me that

> "Exit code 13 is returned from Main when it wants the launcher to display an error message.  Generally, the error message will just be "an error has occurred, check your log file".  Look for a log file in your configuration directory."

Some of these errors have been caused by not having the correct java version installed ([Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)), while others seem to have been caused by a "#" character in their eclipse directory (http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t105198.html).

Maybe one of these reasons causes the crash.

Answer (score 1):

Install all in 64bit.

Then to run (emulate) your Eclipse in 32bit

Just: insert an argument in:
Run Configurations... -> Arguments (tab) -> Program arguments : Type -d32

Answer (score 1):

Old question but it seems worth answering. I just had this problem with an RCP based on features. It turned out that I was exporting the RCP with the feature projects closed. When I opened them and exported the product again, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

try moving the project to the root of the drive

> c:\test\eclipse\

Answer (score 0):

solved:D
1. check the operating system is it 32 bit or 64 bit.. but i think its not problem on my computer because i am using 32 bit jdk and 32 bit eclipse on my windows 7 64 bit.
2. if u still have problem ... try to move eclipse to C:/ its work for my friends.. with problem returned error 13

Comment: Could you clean up your answer? (Capitalization, grammar, formatting, etc...)