# Eclipse wont work

Tags: eclipse, exit-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)

i just downloaded "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers".
After unzipping and editing eclipse.ini the program gets terminated (exit code 13) and shows me the following error message:

[image]

more details:

1. im using windows 7 64 bit.
2. downloaded Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 64 bit for windows.
3. installed java jdk 7.0.4 (in advance)
4. installed sdk for android. (in advance)
5. i followed instructions about editing eclipse.ini and adding the pathway to the javaw.exe
6. this is my eclipse.ini:

   ```
   -startup 
   plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
   --launcher.library
   plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
   -product
   org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
   --launcher.defaultAction
   openFile
   --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
   256M
   -showsplash
   org.eclipse.platform
   --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
   256m
   --launcher.defaultAction
   openFile
   -vm
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin\javaw.exe
   -vmargs 
   -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
   -Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
   -Xms40m
   -Xmx384m
   ```

Comment: I already went through that "possible duplicate" but no comment helped me... BTW the -vm and path are in seperate lines in my file

Answer (score 2):

If you downloaded a 64 bit package of Eclipse, then your Java VM must be 64 bit (and that is independent of your Windows bitsize). But you point to a JVM for 32 bit using the `Program Files (x86)` path.

Please download and install the 64 bit Java instead and point to that location afterwards in your eclipse.ini.

Comment: the java jdk is already installed.. could i dl the 32bit version of eclipse instead.. i also have android SDK which didnt say if its 32 or 64 bit platform.. do u have an idea about the latest version of it ?? http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: ok i downloaded the 32 bit version of eclipse and got the same error saying: "A JRE or JDK must be available in order to run eclipse, no JVM was found at the following path..."

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to include the VM path in double-quotes like:

```
-vm "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin\javaw.exe"
```

Then you should try to exchange the backslashes by slashes:

```
-vm "C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/javaw.exe"
```

Instead of manipulating your `eclipse.ini` file, you could define a startup shortcut or batch file for it. Contents could be:

```
<path to eclipse>\eclipse.exe -vm "c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin\javaw.exe"
```

And yes, your ini file was one of 64bit eclipse distro ...

Comment: ok i put the path in double quotes and now there is a different error but i think we're almost there.. this is the printscreen: http://s14.postimage.org/ft310fkg1/Capture.jpg   it says there is no JVM although its there and the link is correct

Comment: I believe the -vm switch must be on the first line of the eclipse.ini file. Also, the path should be on the next line. Not on the same line as the switch.

Comment: did that. still doesnt work....