# How to start extracted eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)

I downloaded Eclipse eclipse-jee-galileo-SR2-win32 in zip format then I extract the same on my harddisk.
So when I clicked on eclipse.exe I am getting following window as alert.
Though I have java 1.6_35 installed on my machine.[image]

After googling a lot so far I am unable to rid on this.
how to start eclipse now.
same is working fine on other machine.

Comment: BTW, why use Galileo? There are newer ones around...

Comment: @  ppeterka: I tried even Juno version also that also giving me same window on clicking eclipse.exe

Comment: @yatinbc Did you try the solutions provided in Tichodroma's link?

Comment: If this also happens with other Eclipse downloads, then either your ZIP program does not extract the archives correctly or your Java installation is somehow broken.

Answer (score 0):

Check your eclipse.ini file (in the same folder as the exe). Maybe it does not point to the location where your java is installed. 
Search for a line like this

```
-vm c:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_22/bin/javaw.exe
```

Comment: @ Anna: no such line is there in eclipse.ini

Comment: Itf it's not there then where to add it?

Comment: It seems you have an earlier version of eclipse. Can you post your eclipse ini file?

Comment: My eclipse ini file content-----------startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.201.R35x_v20090715.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.0.200.v20090519
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m

Comment: Yeah, what Sajan said: get a 32-bit Java to run Eclipse. Or get a 64-bit Eclipse. And while you are at it: why not download the newest version of Eclipse?

Comment: Anna: I have all versions of Eclipse, none of them is working, all are giving same screen.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if your jvm is 32 bit.
you can find by running 
`java -version` .
you have eclipse for 32-bit jvm (-arch x86).

Comment: My eclipse and jvm both are of 32-bit. And after executing java -version I am getting -------java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.10-b01, mixed mode)