# Downgrading from jdk 1.7 to 1.6 stops my eclipse indigo from working

Tags: java, eclipse, java-7

I was running jdk1.7 in my windows 7 laptop .I had to downgrade to jdk 1.6 as my apk builds dint work with jdk 1.7 when it gets published in google play[Note: im using unity game engine to develop].

After downgrading im getting a eclipse crash.
I tried updating env variables still no hope.
Please find attachment for theerror i get when i run eclipse indigo

OS: windows 7 64 bit

Eclipse : 64 bit

android sdk : 32 bit

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: Try starting Eclipse from the command line with the `-clean` option: `eclipse -clean`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to your statement, your Eclipse is actually a 32-bit variant. See "...win32.x86" in the launcher file name. If it was a 64-bit variant, it would have been "...win32.x86_64".

Eclipse fails to start because 32-bit Eclipse cannot launch on a 64-bit JVM. Either get a 64-bit Eclipse install or install an additional 32-bit JVM and point Eclipse to it use -vm switch in eclipse.ini file.

Comment: Hello konstantin, if that is the issue why would it work when i had jdk 1.7? Only after downgrading it to 1.6 it stopped working.Can you figure why that happened?

Comment: Perhaps you had a 32-bit Java 7 VM and then replaced it with a 64-bit Java 6 VM.

Comment: That is strange cos i remember having a 64 bit java!! but anyways my issue is resolved when i switched to 64 bit eclipse.Thank you

Comment: A common cause of 32-bit Java installs on 64-bit Windows is the Java plugin for Web browsers, since most browsers are still 32-bit. It is even possible that you had both 64-bit and 32-bit versions of Java installed due to this (one installed yourself, one installed as part of browser plugin install).