# Eclipse not working, exit code 13

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse

```
Java was started but returned exit code=13
-Djava.class.path=C:Wevelopment\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219 \ eclipse\ pl ugins\       org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar 
-os win32 
-ws win32 
-arch x86 
-showsplash 
-launcher 
C:Wevelopment\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219 \ eclipse\ eclipse.exe 
-name Eclipse 
--launcher.library 
C:Wevelopment\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219 \ eclipse\ plugins\ org.eclipse. equinox.launcher.win32.win32.46_1.1.200.v20120522-1813 eclipse_1503.d11 -startup 
C: \ Development\ adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219 \eclipse\ plugins\ org.eclipse.   equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar 
--launcher.overrideVmargs 
-vm CAProgram Files\lava\jre7 bin \ client\jvm.dll 
-vmargs 
-Djava.class.pathr CADevelopmentl. adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219 \ eclipse\ pl ugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
```

I am running windows 7 32-bit and just downloaded the ADT Bundle for windows from here http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download 32-bit only. It is throwing this error everytime I run it.

Please help me solve this problem.

P.S. - Beginner

Thanks

Comment: Please see the same Error<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13>
Hope it helps