# Ecllipse Cannot run, JVM Terminated Exitcode-13

Tags: java, android, eclipse

[image]

Hi All, Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13 I've a problem which was shown in Image, it appear when i open the Ecllipse in my Pc, Anyboby face this Problem and have a solution?, Kindly help me, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13 -- search first

Comment: try repeating this exact same invocation using java.exe from a command line instead of javaw,exe, you might get more details printed to the console. i have a feeling it has something to do with that "!@#" part in the paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here: [Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)

One of the answers is:

> I had the same error when configuring eclipse.ini to use JRE6. Turns
>   out I caused this error by incorrectly configuring eclipse to use the
>   64 bit JVM while running a 32 bit version of eclipse 3.7.
>
> The correct configuration required the eclipse.ini -vm argumument to
>   use "C:/Program Files (x86)/" instead of "C:/Program Files/".
>
> Make sure that the JVM version (32/64 bit) you use matches the eclipse
>   version (32/64 bit).

Most answers say only one thing: wrong version of JVM for Eclipse.
Please reconfigure and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much,finally i got the answer by your answer, thank's again :)