# how to put javaw.exe where eclipse can find it

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I had to install an updated version of Java RE. My installed version of eclipse complained that it couldn't find it.  This eclipse came with a complete ADT download.  The specific error message was that it couldn't find javaw.exe in the eclipse\jre\bin sub-directory of the adt-bundle directory.  I copied javaw.exe to that sub directory.  This time Eclipse tried to start, but came back with an Error code 13 and a long list of stuff that wasn't very enlightening.  Please help.

Comment: That long list of stuff might be enlightening to anyone trying to answer.  Sounds like you have a 32/64-bit mismatch between your JRE and the ADT bundle.

Answer (score 2):

just reinstall JDK 32/64-bit, re-extact eclipse-32/64bit and edit eclipse.ini again

Check your eclipse.ini file and see if following required are well written :

***Note:***

the format of the -vm option - it is important to be exact:

**1. The -vm option and its value (the path) must be on separate lines.**

**2. The value must be the full absolute or relative path to the Java executable, not just to the Java home directory.**

**3. The -vm option must occur before the -vmargs option, since everything after -vmargs is passed directly to the JVM.**

Check [this link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM) for reference.

And [also this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to download JDK and JRE from:-

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Also create `PATH` enviroment variable on you computer like this:

Right click on My Computer > Properties > Advanced > Enviroment variables > New ( Variable name: PATH Variable value : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\bin (Where you installed Java)) > Click OK! Done

[image]

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the JDK again and re-installed it and re-transferred the javaw.exe to the sub directory where Eclipse wanted it (...\eclipse\jre\bin) and it worked fine.  My previous download of the JDK must have been somehow corrupted