# Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated with Exit code=13

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jvm

I just append -vm 
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\javaw.exe`

in eclipse.ini then I try to start eclipse again and got this error. Give me how to solve or link that actually solve it.

this is my eclipse.ini

```
-startup

plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar

--launcher.library

plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807

-product

com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize

256M

-showsplash

com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product

-vm

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\javaw.exe
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize

256m

--launcher.defaultAction

openFile

-vmargs

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6

-Xms40m

-Xmx768m

-Declipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M]
```

[See image here]

[image]

Comment: IS there C:/Program Files (x86) in your C drive with java inside it

Comment: ya there is a file like that too

Comment: include that javaw.exe in eclipse.ini and try.

Comment: Im sorry there is no such file in my C:/Program Files (x86) file.... i mistook the question.... I only have it saved in the path i have given in my .ini file above

Comment: You are using a 64 bit JRE with a 32 bit Eclipse - they must both be 64 bit or both 32 bit.

Comment: Thankz it worked... I didnt notice properly

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on the below url.

[Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)

Comment: I have the path only in the next line of -vm n before -vmargs as said in that link... but still i get the same error

Comment: Exactly this error is wat I have... but I have done all the changes in the answer suggested has given.... my previous comment answers it perfectly....

Comment: im not able to upload the picture as i dont have reputation score as this is my first tym posting my questions or seeking answers here