# JVM terminated. Exit code=13

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-juno

I have downloaded **eclipse 64 bit and my os is 64 bit fedora**
but am getting below error when i try to open eclipse..

i dont know its a os issue or eclipse issue

when i type java - version

iam being shown with

**java version "1.7.0_51"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (fedora-2.4.5.1.fc20-x86_64 u51-b31)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)**

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /home/kranthikumar.sama/Downloads/Eclipse/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86
-showsplash /home/kranthikumar.sama/Downloads/Eclipse/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.1.v201209141800/splash.bmp
-launcher /home/kranthikumar.sama/Downloads/Eclipse/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/kranthikumar.sama/Downloads/Eclipse/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813/eclipse_1502.so
-startup /home/kranthikumar.sama/Downloads/Eclipse/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 260005
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.dsl.product
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /home/kranthikumar.sama/Downloads/Eclipse/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
```

here is my eclipse.ini file

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.dsl.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)

Comment: @Jens i dont think its a duplicate.am using fedora os but the link to other question is windows..

Comment: @KranthiSama Please show us your `eclipse.ini`

Comment: @Absurd-Mind i have added my eclipse.ini contents

Comment: You are using a 32 bit Eclipse - it must be 64 bit to match the JRE.

Comment: I have downloaded a fresh copy of eclipse 64 bit. and now its wrkng