# Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13 unlike others

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I guess this is something like this:
[Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)
But I do not want to have to completely reinstall Eclipse.

So, since I do not want to reinstall eclipse, I was hoping someone could look at my error message and my eclipse.ini and give me some ideas.

Here is the error message that pops up when I try to run eclipse on my red hat:

```
 JVM terminated. Exit code=13
 /usr/bin/java
 -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
 -Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
 -Xms40m
 -Xmx512m
 -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=webkit
 -jar /rhel5pdi/apollo/var/env/eclipse-4.2/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
 -os linux
 -ws gtk
 -arch x86_64
 -showsplash /rhel5pdi/apollo/var/env/eclipse-4.2/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200/splash.bmp
 -launcher /rhel5pdi/apollo/var/env/eclipse-4.2/eclipse/eclipse
 -name Eclipse
 --launcher.library /rhel5pdi/apollo/var/env/eclipse-4.2/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807/eclipse_1502.so
 -startup /rhel5pdi/apollo/var/env/eclipse-4.2/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
 --launcher.overrideVmargs
 -exitdata 2c0012
 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
 -vm /usr/bin/java
 -vmargs
 -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
 -Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
 -Xms40m
 -Xmx512m
 -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=webkit
 -jar /rhel5pdi/apollo/var/env/eclipse-4.2/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
```

============

## Here is the eclipse.ini

```
 --launcher.library
 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
 -product
 org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
 --launcher.defaultAction
 openFile
 -showsplash
 org.eclipse.platform
 --launcher.defaultAction
 openFile
 -startup
 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
 -vmargs
 -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
 -Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
 -Xms40m
 -Xmx512m
 -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=webkit
```

Comment: did you update your eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while back. I eventually found the solution in a post on StackOverflow (will cite when I remember where). The poster mentioned something pertaining to the "eclipse holy trinity". This refers to Eclipse, JRE/JDK, and OS all being of the same architecture. So 32bit/32bit/32bit or 64bit/64bit/64bit.

Answer (score 0):

Exit code 13 is (always) due to a bit-ness mismatch between Eclipse and the JVM it's running in; they must both be either 32-bit or 64-bit. Many people run into trouble because they *think* they're running Eclipse in a specific JVM but have not properly specified it in `eclipse.ini` and so Eclipse picks up the incorrect one.
Read the [`eclipse.ini` wiki page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM) **carefully** to learn how to specify the full path to a JVM (preferably a JDK) that you want Eclipse to run in. I repeat: read the instructions *fully* and *carefully* as the format is very particular.

Alternatively, you can use the Eclipse Installer which automatically locates an appropriate JVM on your machine, or directs you where to get one if it can't find one. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31885692/639520

Comment: I am not aware of a trinity (sic), but eclipse neon 32 bit runs fine on Java 1.8 32 bit on a 64 bit Linux Debian.  All you needed were that Java and eclipse have the same architecture.