# Unable to start Eclipse Mars on OSX

Tags: eclipse, macos

The reason is because I have an outdated JVM version(1.6_5).My Google searches direct me to open a Java Control Panel which is not where it should be under System Preferences on my system.

Comment: Please include which version of eclipse you are trying to use, java/c/c++ etc. Also, when trying to start it you should be informed of which JDK you need to install to operate eclipse.

Comment: Install the Java 8 JDK (must be JDK not the JRE) from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [Eclipse Installer](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/installer.php), it will detect what JVMs you have and direct you where to get an appropriate one if you don't already have it.