# STS(Spring Tool Suite) Not opening

Tags: java, spring

I am not able to open the spring tool suite in the centos.

Following is the exception which is causing this problem.:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/opt/jdk1.7.0_60/bin/java
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m  //plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
-jar /home/kapil/Desktop/springsource/sts-3.4.0.RELEASE
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash  
-launcher /home/kapil/Desktop/springsource/sts-3.4.0.RELEASE/STS
-name STS
--launcher.library /home/kapil/Desktop/springsource/sts-3.4.0.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835/eclipse_1506.so
-startup /home/kapil/Desktop/springsource/sts-3.4.0.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 30000d
-product org.springsource.sts.ide
-vm /opt/jdk1.7.0_60/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /home/kapil/Desktop/springsource/sts-3.4.0.RELEASE//plugins /org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
```

Here is the output of the `java -version` command :-

```
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
```

And here is the output of the `which java` command :-

```
/usr/bin/java
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the JVM version (32/64 bit) you use matches the eclipse version (32/64 bit).
Add this line in your sts.ini file and test again 
-vm 
/ur_java_home/bin/javaw.exe

Comment: I am using both with the 64 bit version only.Problem is previously i was having open-jdk which was crashing sts or I don't know what was happening.So I installed oracle jdk 1.7. From their that problem is coming.

Comment: Add this line in your sts.ini file and test again </br>-vm </br>/urjavahome/bin/javaw.exe

Answer (score 0):

First location to check is whether your JDK is 32 bit or 64 bit. Next, sheck your sts.ini configuration values. Trial and error will see you through.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to work
Note that is on my system.

`-vm
    C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_144/bin/javaw.exe
    -startup
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
    –launcher.library
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.551.v20171108-1834
    -product
    com.springsource.sts.ide
    –launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
    –launcher.XXMaxPermSize
    384M
    -vmargs
    -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
    -Xmn128m
    -Xms256m
    -Xmx768m
    -Xss4m
    -XX:PermSize=128m
    -XX:MaxPermSize=384m
    -XX:CompileThreshold=1000
    -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
    -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
    -XX:+UseG1GC
    -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue on Mac. If it is Mac, below is the fix.

Go to the terminal and run the below command & enter your login password.

```
sudo codesign --force --sign - /Applications/SpringToolSuite4.app
```